# tcolorbox: Round height up to the next multiple of a given dimension

Tags: tcolorbox, grids

I have started to use the very powerful package `tcolorbox`. One thing I would like to achieve is producing a grid for school exercise sheets. I think am almost there. But it would be nice to create a box, for which the height is calculated in the following way.

The natural height of the box for the available content should be calculated. That dimension should then be rounded up to the next integer multiple of a given length. Then the height of the box should be set to that result.

The idea is that the grid looks symmetric at the top and at the bottom.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtcolorbox{mygrid}{breakable, colback=white, enhanced, 
    boxrule=0pt, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt, top=9pt, left=13pt, right=13pt, bottom=10pt,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \filldraw[help lines, black!15, step=0.04\linewidth,
                shift={($0.5*(interior.north west)+0.5*(interior.north east)
                    -0.02*(0,\linewidth)$)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mygrid}
Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. 
Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. 
Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. 
Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.  
\end{mygrid}
\end{document}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does not choosing the same value for `top` and `bottom` do this?